# Custom NSButton not displaying as expected

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsbutton

I'm trying to make a custom NSButton with rounded corner, shadow and flat.

This is how I want it to look (HTML/CSS demo [here](https://jsbin.com/guyazojabo/edit?css,output)):
[image]

(The partial bold label and hover effect is off scope)

I'm using this code:

```
@IBDesignable class FlatButton: NSButton {
    @IBInspectable let backgroundColor: NSColor = .white

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        // Set corner radius
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.cornerRadius = 18
        self.layer?.borderWidth = 0
        self.layer?.borderColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
        layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
        frame.size.height = 32
        
        // Darken background color when highlighted
        if isHighlighted {
            layer?.backgroundColor =  backgroundColor.blended(
                withFraction: 0.2, of: .black
            )?.cgColor
        } else {
            layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
        }
        
        self.shadow = NSShadow()
        self.layer?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 8, height: 18)
        self.layer?.shadowColor = .black
        self.layer?.shadowRadius = 9
        self.layer?.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer?.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        
        // Super
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

But here's what I get with that code:

(With borders)

[image]

(No border)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something that I don't understand about your question, but creating a custom button from an NSView subclass and using mouse events seems to work ok.  The hover feature could be added with a tracking area.

```
import Cocoa

var isSelected : Bool
isSelected = false

class CustomView: NSView {

 override func draw(_ rect: NSRect ) {
 super.draw(rect)
 let backgroundColor: NSColor = .white

 // Set corner radius
 self.wantsLayer = true
 self.layer?.cornerRadius = 18
 self.layer?.borderWidth = 0
 self.layer?.borderColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
 layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
 frame.size.height = 32
 
 // Shadow
 self.shadow = NSShadow()
 self.layer?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 8, height: 18)
 self.layer?.shadowColor = .black
 self.layer?.shadowRadius = 9
 self.layer?.masksToBounds = false
 self.layer?.shadowOpacity = 0.5
       
 // Darken background color when selected
  if isSelected {
   layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.blended( withFraction: 0.2, of: .black )?.cgColor
   } else {
   layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
  }

 // Add attributed text
 let text: NSString = "Custom button test"
 let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
 let attr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font,.foregroundColor: NSColor.red]
 text.draw(at:NSMakePoint(50,5), withAttributes:attr)
}

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
 print("mouse down in button.")
 isSelected = true
 self.needsDisplay = true 
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
 print("mouse up in button.")
 isSelected = false
 self.needsDisplay = true
}

}

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

func buildMenu() {
let mainMenu = NSMenu()
 NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
 // **** App menu **** //
 let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
 mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
 appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q") 
}

func buildWnd() {
 let _wndW : CGFloat = 500
 let _wndH : CGFloat = 400

let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH ), styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

// **** Custom view **** //
 let view = CustomView( frame:NSMakeRect(60, _wndH - 160, 300, 32)) 
 view.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]      
 window.contentView!.addSubview (view)
    
// **** Quit btn **** //
 let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
}
 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let applicationDelegate = ApplicationDelegate()

let application = NSApplication.shared
application.setActivationPolicy(NSApplication.ActivationPolicy.regular)
application.delegate = applicationDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I add the shadow and the text though?

Comment: We should be able to use an attributed string for text and shadow.  I was not able to get the shadow to work in your post, so I'm not sure how that's supposed to look.  I will try to add it if you show me the effect that you want (perhaps I missed it).  Text example is shown in my edited answer.

Comment: If you set .maskToBounds to false, the shadow will show up.  See second edit to answer.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't worked with NSViews before like this. How do I link the click action from the design section to the viewcontroller ? I have several buttons that have different click actions

Comment: It just allows me to add a new outlet to the viewcontroller.  The NSView doesn't have the "sent actions" section

Answer (score 0):

In order to have less work for your draw function, a lot of the view customization could be done when the window is initialized:

```
import Cocoa

var isSelected : Bool
isSelected = false

class CustomView: NSView {

 override func draw(_ rect: NSRect ) {
 super.draw(rect)

 let backgroundColor: NSColor = .white
       
 // Darken background color when selected
 if isSelected {
  layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.blended( withFraction: 0.2, of: .black )?.cgColor
  } else {
  layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
 }

 // Add attributed text
 let text: NSString = "Custom button text"
 let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
 let attr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font,.foregroundColor: NSColor.red]
 text.draw(at:NSMakePoint(50,5), withAttributes:attr)
}

func myBtnAction( ) {
  NSSound.beep()
}

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
 print("mouse down in button.")
 isSelected = true
 self.needsDisplay = true 
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
 print("mouse up in button.")
 isSelected = false
 myBtnAction()
 self.needsDisplay = true
}

}

class ApplicationDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

func buildMenu() {
let mainMenu = NSMenu()
 NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
 // **** App menu **** //
 let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
 mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
 appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q") 
}

func buildWnd() {
 let _wndW : CGFloat = 500
 let _wndH : CGFloat = 400

let window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH ), styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

// **** Custom view **** //
 let view = CustomView( frame:NSMakeRect(60, _wndH - 160, 300, 32)) 
 view.autoresizingMask = [.maxXMargin,.minYMargin]       
 view.wantsLayer = true
 view.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
 view.layer?.cornerRadius = 18
 view.layer?.borderWidth = 2
 view.layer?.shadowColor = NSColor.black.cgColor
 view.layer?.shadowRadius = 9
 view.layer?.shadowOpacity = 0.5
 view.layer?.masksToBounds = false
 window.contentView!.addSubview (view)

// **** Quit btn **** //
 let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)
}
 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let applicationDelegate = ApplicationDelegate()

let application = NSApplication.shared
application.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
application.delegate = applicationDelegate
application.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
application.run()
```

Comment: To connect an action for the custom view button see edited second answer.  Add a new function called 'myBtnAction' to the view class and call it when the mouse is released.

Comment: What if I have several NSViews ? What can I make sure each NSView has its own action? Wouldn't it be better to add these styles in an NSButton?

Comment: Probably would have to use a separate class for each button or alternatively an array of views depending on how many buttons you have.  You could also add images or attributed text to NSButtons, but I don't think you'll be able to get those nice round corners like you have on the custom button; your call.

Comment: Another possibility: https://bluelemonbits.com/2020/04/04/create-a-nsbutton-in-code-swift/

Answer (score 0):

The following is a modification of the technique for creating an NSButton in code described by Marc Marset (referenced above) and should meet your requirements.  The 'customNSButton' function will allow the creation of multiple buttons with individualized actions set by Target-Action for each button.  A timer is used to 'wink' the background color and a shadow is created below the button.  The title is attributed text.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
var window:NSWindow!
var button:NSButton!

@objc func resetBkgrndColor(_ sender:AnyObject) {
 let backgroundColor: NSColor = .white
 button.layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor
}

@objc func myBtnAction(_ sender:AnyObject ) {
 let backgroundColor: NSColor = .white
 button.layer?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.blended( withFraction: 0.2, of: .black )?.cgColor
 Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.25, target:self, selector:#selector(self.resetBkgrndColor(_:)), userInfo:nil, repeats:false)
 NSSound.beep()
}

func customNSButton( bkgrndColor: NSColor?, borderColor: NSColor?, borderWidth: CGFloat?, cornerRadius: CGFloat? ) -> NSButton {        
 button = NSButton()
    
 button.wantsLayer = true
 button.layer?.backgroundColor = bkgrndColor?.cgColor ?? .clear
 button.layer?.masksToBounds = true
 button.layer!.cornerRadius = cornerRadius ?? 0
 button.layer!.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
 button.layer!.borderWidth = borderWidth ?? 0

 button.layer?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 8, height: 18)
 button.layer?.shadowColor = .black
 button.layer?.shadowRadius = 9
 button.layer?.masksToBounds = false
 button.layer?.shadowOpacity = 0.5
      
 return button
}

func buildMenu() {
 let mainMenu = NSMenu()
 NSApp.mainMenu = mainMenu
 // **** App menu **** //
 let appMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
 mainMenu.addItem(appMenuItem)
 let appMenu = NSMenu()
 appMenuItem.submenu = appMenu
 appMenu.addItem(withTitle: "Quit", action:#selector(NSApplication.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q") 
}
    
func buildWnd() {
    
let _wndW : CGFloat = 400
let _wndH : CGFloat = 300

 window = NSWindow(contentRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,_wndW,_wndH),styleMask:[.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable], backing:.buffered, defer:false)
 window.center()
 window.title = "Swift Test Window"
 window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)

// **** Custom Button **** //
 let myBtn = customNSButton(bkgrndColor:.white, borderColor:.black, borderWidth:2, cornerRadius:22)
 myBtn.frame = NSMakeRect(60,120,300,40)
 myBtn.bezelStyle = .roundRect
 myBtn.isBordered = false
 myBtn.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Btn Text", attributes: [.foregroundColor: NSColor.red, .font:NSFont(name:"Menlo Bold", size:28)])
 myBtn.action = #selector(self.myBtnAction(_:))
 window.contentView!.addSubview(myBtn)

// **** Quit btn **** //
 let quitBtn = NSButton (frame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 50, 10, 40, 40 ))
 quitBtn.bezelStyle = .circular
 quitBtn.autoresizingMask = [.minXMargin,.maxYMargin]
 quitBtn.title = "Q"
 quitBtn.action = #selector(NSApplication.terminate)
 window.contentView!.addSubview(quitBtn)

}
 
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
 buildMenu()
 buildWnd()
}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
 return true
}

}
let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** main.swift **** //
let app = NSApplication.shared
app.delegate = appDelegate
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
app.activate(ignoringOtherApps:true)
app.run()
```